# how to create a project server side running(SSR) ReactJS with typescript language

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

recently i know ssr but don't know how to create a project.

and how to connect the server with the client in the same folder.

I watched some videos on youtobe, it was instructed to use vite but when I tried to connect the server to the client, it failed.

server.js

```
import fs from "node:fs/promises";
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
import userRouters from "./server/routes/userRoutes.js";

// Constants
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const port = process.env.PORT || 5173;
const base = process.env.BASE || "/";

// Cached production assets
const templateHtml = isProduction
  ? await fs.readFile("./dist/client/index.html", "utf-8")
  : "";
const ssrManifest = isProduction
  ? await fs.readFile("./dist/client/ssr-manifest.json", "utf-8")
  : undefined;

// Create http server
const app = express();

// Add Vite or respective production middlewares
let vite;
if (!isProduction) {
  const { createServer } = await import("vite");
  vite = await createServer({
    server: { middlewareMode: true },
    appType: "custom",
    base,
  });
  app.use(vite.middlewares);
} else {
  const compression = (await import("compression")).default;
  const sirv = (await import("sirv")).default;
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(base, sirv("./dist/client", { extensions: [] }));
}

// Serve HTML
app.use("*", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const url = req.originalUrl.replace(base, "");

    let template;
    let render;
    if (!isProduction) {
      // Always read fresh template in development
      template = await fs.readFile("./index.html", "utf-8");
      template = await vite.transformIndexHtml(url, template);
      render = (await vite.ssrLoadModule("/src/entry-server.tsx")).render;
    } else {
      template = templateHtml;
      render = (await import("./dist/server/entry-server.js")).render;
    }

    const rendered = await render(url, ssrManifest);

    const html = template
      .replace(`<!--app-head-->`, rendered.head ?? "")
      .replace(`<!--app-html-->`, rendered.html ?? "");

    res.status(200).set({ "Content-Type": "text/html" }).end(html);
  } catch (e) {
    vite?.ssrFixStacktrace(e);
    console.log(e.stack);
    res.status(500).end(e.stack);
  }
});

// server
dotenv.config();
app.use(cors());

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_LINK, () => {
  console.log("Connect to mongodb...");
});
app.use("/api/user", userRouters);

// Start http server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

can anyone explain it to me when i `run npm run dev` it runs ssr but when i run `npm start` it runs csr

Can someone explain to me if I can see some websites `view page source` with css and I don't. I do not know why